# select all h3 elements and label them based off of a date pattern

Tags: javascript, html, getelementbyid

```
<h3>Thursday, April 7th, 2016 - Wednesday, April 13th, 2016</h3> 
<h3>Thursday, April 14th, 2016 - Wednesday, April 20th, 2016</h3>
<h3>Thursday, April 21st, 2016 - Wednesday, April 27th, 2016</h3>

<script>
var $h3s = $('h3');        
for (var i = 0; i < $h3s.length; i++) {
        var element = $h3s[i];
        var $h3 = $(element);
        var today = 'Thursday, May 14th, 2016';
            $h3.html( $h3.html() + " " + today);

    }
    </script>
```

Is there a way to use Javascript to select all h3 elements and label them based off of the above pattern? I know how to select and iterate through all h3 elements and name them all the same, but instead I want to name them based off of this date pattern.

Comment: I don't understand this question. Do you have a list of dates that you want to display as h3 elements?

Comment: Do you mean date format when you mention date pattern?

Comment: Please clarify your question. I'm pretty confused as to what you mean by "the above pattern," "label them", and "name them."

Answer (score 0):

To select all the `h3` elements, you can use `getElementsByTagName()`.

```
var x = document.getElementsByTagName("h3");
```

you can then use this variable `x` to do whatever you want.

According to the [documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbytagname.asp) of `getElementsByTagName()`  :

> The getElementsByTagName() method returns a collection of all elements
>   in the document with the specified tag name, as a NodeList object.
>
> The NodeList object represents a collection of nodes. The nodes can be
>   accessed by index numbers. The index starts at 0.

Answer (score 0):

From the codes you have attemped I am thinking you want something like this..

```js
var all_h3=document.getElementsByTagName('h3');
var today='Thursday, May 14th, 2016';
for(var i=0;i<all_h3.length;++i){
all_h3[i].innerHTML+=" "+today
}
```

```html
<h3>Thursday, April 7th, 2016 - Wednesday, April 13th, 2016</h3> 
<h3>Thursday, April 14th, 2016 - Wednesday, April 20th, 2016</h3>
<h3>Thursday, April 21st, 2016 - Wednesday, April 27th, 2016</h3>
```